# I want to get whatsapp images in my php website using whatsapi. is it possible?

Tags: php, api, whatsapp

I have seen this link :
http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/
In this link all the things are shown how to send message and all but there is no any method to get images from whatsapp to php web app. 
Please help me doing this task.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please give me solution guyz! I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must subscribe to the events that are fired when  items are received. e.g

```
$this->wa->eventManager()->bind('onGetMessage', array($this, 'processReceivedMessage'));
```

have a look at the examples here https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the events that are fired when media items are received. The events are named onGetImage and onGetVideo. For all available events and their properties have a look at the event class from WhatsApi.